# How to load individual REX slices into Live's Drum Rack slots?

Tags: ableton-live

In Ableton Live 9, how can I load a single slice of a Recycle loop into a Drum Rack pad/slot as a 1-shot? There is a tab labeled "1-shot" but it always triggers from the first slice and then plays the whole loop. I would like to be able to designate any single slice of the .rx2 file to be triggered by that Drum Rack pad. Thanks.

[image: Ableton Live Drum rack with Recycle (REX) file loaded]

Answer (score 1):

Select **Slice** mode from the left side (Classic / 1-Shot / Slice), right-click on the waveform display and select **Slice to Drum Rack** from the menu. This will create a Drum Rack with a separate pad for each slice.

In older versions of Live where the REX loop player shown in the question isn't available, you can achieve the same result by dragging the loop to an audio track, right-clicking on the audio clip and selecting **Slice to New MIDI Track**. This will give you some options, but you can select the Built-in slicing preset.

Comment: Thank you! However, when I R-click on a slice I only see `Slice to New MIDI Track`. what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know, maybe you have an older version? I tested with 9.7.2. But you can use Slice to New MIDI Track as well, it will create the drum rack and a MIDI clip to go with it. You can delete the clip if you don't need it. Slice to Drum Rack seems to be the same, but without creating a clip.